# Question regarding converting analog sensor value into mA

Tags: humidity, sensor

I'm doing a project with an absolute humidity sensor.

When I bought an absolute humidity sensor and implemented it into a machine, I expected the output value to be representative of absolute humidity, but the output I received from the sensor is an analog value that ranges from 0 - 4096.

As I examined the datasheet of the sensor, I realized that it produced a milliampere output that ranged from 4 - 20 mA, and based on this value, I needed to calculate the absolute humidity value using a formula they provided.

But the output I receive is an analog value that ranges from 0 - 4096.

So my question is, how do I calculate/convert the analog value (0 - 4096) I receive at the moment, into a milliampere value ranging from 4 - 20 mA, so I can use it in my formula in order to calculate the absolute humidity value?

It is my hope that my explanation will clear up any confusion.

Comment: What do you mean by you are 'missing the mA out' - you have an equation for what the output current will be as a function of absolute humidity and temperature...

Comment: Do you mean *digital* value 0-4095? Where does the value come from?

Comment: My apologies for any confusion. Let me edit the post, elaborate further, and remove some redundant information

Comment: Can somebody tell me how to take this conversation to chat?

Comment: @PaulPham, if I can get your question into a chat room, I can provide more information that may be helpful.

Comment: Of course it's closed because it's about an actual physical instrument used in real physics experiments, not the abstract "physics" of mathematicians.

Comment: I believe what you have is a digital interface that converts an analog signal to a number. An analog to digital converter (ADC). You need to examine the documentation for that. Maybe 4 mA is 0 and 20 mA is 4095, but we can't tell you without knowing what you're using. The documentation on the *sensor* won't help, you need the ADC documentation.

Comment: Hello @DavidWhite, you can write to my email - P.h.v.pham@hotmail.com.
Thank you in advance.

Thank you for your input John Doty, I will try to look into the ADC documentation

Comment: @PaulPham, email has been sent.